# Почему сортировка пузырьком идет так долго?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int n;
cin >> n;
int array[n];
int z = 0;
// input
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;
    array[i] = temp;
}
//sorting
while(z != n-1) {
for(int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
       if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
           swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
       }
       else {
           z++;
       }
    }
}
    //output 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Написал(сам) алгоритм сортировки пузырьком. Работает очень странно. В связи с этим вопрос. Если я ошибся, то где? Если нет, то неужели у этого алгоритма такое чудовищное время выполнения?

Comment: Все примитивные сортировки (в т.ч. "пузырек") имеют время выполнения  `O(N ** 2)` (ага, чудовищно долго для больших массивов). Хорошие же сортировки выполняются за `O(N * log(N))` (это quicksort, mergesort и их разновидности).

Comment: Что значит *"Работает очень странно"*? Что значит *"чудовищное время выполнения"*? *"Если я ошибся, то где?"* — в цэ++ нет массивов переменной длины, например

Comment: @dIm0n, это (об отсутствии VLA) вы g++ расскажите

Comment: @avp с++ != g++

Comment: @dIm0n, кому как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендовал бы делать чуть по другому. Обычная сортировка пузырьком выглядит примерно так:

```
// Сортировка массива пузырьком
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
            // меняем элементы местами
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Быстрее она не станет, те же `O(N ** 2)`

Comment: В цэ++ нет массивов переменной длины

Comment: @dIm0n, и что? Как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov в смысле? — Код невалидный, а участник говорит, что рекомендует делать так

Comment: @dIm0n, речь про запись алгоритма. Ну а для G++ код вполне себе валидный

Comment: @Kir_Antipov речь про запись алгоритма на языке цэ++, а не на псевдокоде. Если автор ответа укажет, что это псевдокод или расширение компилятора, то другое дело

Comment: @dIm0n, так-то определение массива не входит в алгоритм. Ему как раз не то что интересно, что из себя представляет `array`: хоть богомерзкий variable length array, хоть праведный vector

Comment: @Kir_Antipov ещё раз: у вопроса метка [tag:c++], а не [tag:алгоритм] или [tag:любой-язык], значит, предполагаем по умолчанию, что ответ также дан на цэ++, если не сказано обратного. Если код на этом языке некорректный, то я указываю на это. Ну а про то, что интересно ТСу, 1) мы не можем знать; 2) ответ нужен не только ТСу, а базе знаний в целом

Comment: @dIm0n, теперь вам спокойней? :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov нет, теперь считаю, что вы серьёзно изменили чужой ответ без согласия автора, что делать не стоит https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10693/398802

Comment: @dIm0n, что же вы за человек-то такой? :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, очевидно очередная занудная зануда, повернутая на "базе знаний", а  не реальной помощи людям

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, но оба его аргумента справедливы: в плюсах действительно нет  VLA и об этом стоит предупреждать неофитов (особенно с точки зрения уверовавших в священный стандарт)... и значительная правка чужого ответа, дабы лишь завершить бессмысленный спор — это моветон...